# Extract, from huge wav files, audio parts over a certain level

Tags: audio

Imagine a huge audio file with several hours of silence and few minutes, maybe seconds, of voice.

Is there a way, ideally on Linux (*sox*, *avconv*, ...), to extract only the part with the voice and store it as a standalone audio file?

Answer (score 0):

From [sox documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

Found a solution:

```
sox input.wav output.wav silence 1 0.1 1% -1 0.1 1%
```